# iText 5.0.0 large table handling

Tags: itext

Coming straight to the point

I am constructing a large table which is getting data from a backend.

I am using Itextsharp 5.0.0. Not possible to upgrade due to specific reasons

I have a parent table where I am adding all tables as cell.

In the parent table I am adding following properties

SplitRows to true
SplitLate to false
KeepTogether  to false

In the child table following properties are added
KeepTogether to  false
splitRows to  false; //for some table
After getting all the rows from different function which is being called into main table, I am applying SetExtendedRow to false
Then I am adding that table to pdfdocument.

Main Table structure

[image: Main Table Structure]

```
private PdfPTable mainTable()
{
   //PdfPTableHelper.Create-> Create Table without border
   //Create(1->Number of column)
   PdfPTable mainTable= PdfPTableHelper.Create(1);
   mainTable.KeepTogether = false;
   mainTable.SplitRows = true;
   mainTable.SplitLate = false;
   foreach(var part in parts)
   {
      ChildTable1(ref mainTable,part);
      ChildTable2(ref mainTable,part); 
      ChildTable3(ref mainTable,part);
   }
   mainTable.SetExtendedRow(false,false);
}
private PdfPTable ChildTable1(ref PdfPTable    mainTable,XElement part)
{
   PdfPTable childTable1 = PdfPTableHelper.Create(4);
   childTable1.KeepTogether = false;
   //CreatePdfCell(Value of the cell, font, number of column)
   childTable1.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfCell("Cell1: "+part.Cell1.value,defaultFont,1));
   childTable1.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfCell("Cell2: "+part.Cell2.value,defaultFont,3));
   childTable1.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfCell("Cell3: "+part.Cell3.value,defaultFont,1));
   childTable1.AddCell(CellHelper.CreatePdfCell("Cell14 "+part.Cell4.value,defaultFont,3));
   childTable1.splitRows = false;//For some table
   mainTable.AddCell(childTable1);
}
```

Similarly the other child Tables are getting created and getting added to the main table

All problem comes when itext tries to render the table at the end of the page. My objective is the content can flow across the page. But there should not be any data loss.

If we don't use splitRows to false. For some cases we are loosing one part of the table like below

[image: Data missing from row]

In this image you can see the right side cell2 content is going to the next page. **But at the end of the page the first part of the PdfPRow got missed.** Itext completely ignores that and goes to the next part of the row renders it in the beginning of next page.

**Why that happens? I am tired of searching could not get any relevant information**
If we apply splitRow -> false to that table, the complete row is forwarded to the next page. Keeping considerable amount of space in the last page which is not ok.

[image: SplitRow -> false]

I have below questions

1. What is the drawback of splitLate -> false
   does the data loss happens because of it if yes how to avoid it, I cannot have white space in pages.
2. What property should be applied to the parent table so that it keeps all the child tables intact. Not resulting in any data loss.

I know Itext 5.0.0 is kind of dead. But there's nothing I can do in my case to upgrade it to the latest.

Comment: Tagging @BrunoLowagie

Comment: @mkl -> Please help

Comment: **A** addressing people via @..  only works if they somehow have already commented to your post or updated it. I only stumbled over your post because it's new, not because of that @ comment. **B** There are a number of aspects of itext I'm fairly knowledgeable about but table creation details are not among them. **C** If I were trying table layout magic, I would shy away from using inert tables. Instead I'd use only one layer of table dynamically used with colspans for variable column layouts.

Comment: "Inert" should have been "inner". That's helpful cellular keyboards in action...

Comment: 1. What are the specific reasons? 2. Tagging won't work. 3. Bruno Lowagie no longer works at iText Software, and lately he hasn't been very active on Stack Overflow either.

Comment: @Amedee Van GasseThank you for replying, and for doing the edits. I did not understand your point no 1 . I just want to know when splitLate will result in dataloss or whether the setextendedlast row is the reason of data loss, or it is the header and footer behind which the data is hiding

Comment: @mkl Thank you for replying back. I understand your point. In my case I chose to go for inner tables because some table has header which needs to repeat. If I keep everything I dont know how I will handle that. Also the code the function becomes so huge and cluttered it is difficult to manage.

Comment: My point no 1: you claim to have specific reasons not to upgrade. I ask what those specific reasons are. Not a difficult question to understand I hope?